# Assigning a value to ComboBox using GetElementsByID - Not working?

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, xhtml, vbscript

```
 .getElementById("ComboBox1").setAttribute "value", "value1"
```

I am automating Excel and IE.  Im pulling data from a web page, but I need to pick a value from a combobox (drop down list, and I know the value I need), and this doesnt seem to be working, but I do not get a debug.  How do I set the value of a combo box otherwise?  There is an onchange that occurs but Im not sure if it affects my selection any?  I thought this was the way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `.getElementById("ComboBox1").value = "value1"`?

Comment: Thanks for the alternate code! I ended up using it, and then it turned out there was some weird spacing in the option selection, so that may have been the problem originally.